# How to include #include <QtWin> in the application - QtWinExtras

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT 5.1.1 in MS VS2012 and I cannot include that header. Any suggestions why its saying the header is not found ? Do I have to download it separately ? I need to use QtWinExtras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import directive for QtWin is

```
#include <QtWinExtras>
```

not

```
#include <QtWin>
```

as the subject line of your question suggests.

Also you'll need this in your .pro file

```
QT += winextras
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Qt 5.1 doesn't have Windows extras module, see 5.1 module list [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtmodules.html), so you can update to Qt 5.2, that include Windows extras module or get the source code and build it yourself, i found it on [gitorious](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwinextras/)